# How to count amount of columns which are similar to first column in 2D array(Python)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the task where I need to find number of columns similar to the first one. I have certain array of ***MxN*** size, where numbers within the range of 0 to 100. Firstly, I want to try to solve it with static array (without pseudo random numbers), but I'm stuck and cannot find a solution. So far I have this:

```
firstCol = []
temp = []
amount = 0

table = [[36, 36, 78, 36, 38, 41], 
         [65, 6, 23, 65, 49, 89], 
         [18, 70, 77, 18, 59, 0], 
         [53, 46, 80, 66, 10, 13], 
         [33, 93, 26, 57, 37, 23], 
         [83, 37, 39, 27, 53, 100], 
         [1, 11, 46, 96, 98, 93], 
         [54, 33, 90, 88, 83, 58]]

firstCol = [e1[0] for e1 in table]

theSame = [False] *10 
n=1
temp = [e2[n] for e2 in table]
```

The rest of the code doesn`t work, so I didn't write it here. The idea is to compare values of`firstCol` and temp arrays. Values of temp will change every loop. If there is a better idea how to do that I would be happy to see it, thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my reputation score was high enough, I would comment and say "This looks a bit like a homework assignment."  I would then try to provide you with some guidance as to how to move forward, like I might suggest you research how to iterate through an array.

But since I can only answer questions, I'll provide you with code that accomplishes your goal ( I think ).  Hope this helps:

```
# Lets create a vector/array for our results and initalize it to zero
counts=[0] * len(table)

# step through the two dimensional array... 
for index,row in enumerate(table):
  # The first column is index 0 of the row
  firstValue = row[0]

  # Now just compare the firstValue to the rest of the values in the row
  for colValue in row[1:]:
    if colValue == firstValue:
      counts[index] =  counts[index] + 1


print counts
```

Comment: Oh, i guess i wasn`t clear when described my problem. I needed to compare columns with 1st column and check how many columns are identical to first column. So in case with array i hardcoded it should have returned 1 since only 4th column is the same as 1st.